# Log "date -s" command

Tags: logging, time, date, syslog-ng

I know that the `date -s <STRING>` command sets the time described by the string `STRING`.

What i want is to log the above command whenever it is used to set the time into the file `/tmp/log/user.log`.

In my Linux distribution the logging is done by `syslog-ng`. I already have some logs going into `/tmp/log/user.log`.

This is the content of /etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf in my system for logging into `/tmp/log/user.log`

```
destination d_notice  { file("/tmp/log/user.log");};

filter f_filter10   { level(notice) and not facility(mail,authpriv,cron); };

log { source(s_sys); filter(f_filter10); destination(d_notice); };
```

What should i do so that `date -s` command is also logged into `/tmp/log/user.log`

Answer (score 1):

Date changes are not logged by default, at least not on Debian.

The simplest option would be to replace /bin/date with a wrapper that prints a log message using `logger` then calls the real /bin/date executable, e.g.

```
mv /bin/date /bin/date.real
cat << 'EOF' >/bin/date
#!/bin/bash
logger -p user.notice "date run by $UID: $*"
/bin/date.real
EOF
chmod +x /bin/date
```

Other than that, I know that [grsecurity](http://grsecurity.net/) allows you to log any changes to the system time.  It would require compiling a custom kernel.

Comment: I agree with you. But if i use this, `date -s` command will show the date , `date -<somejunk>` will also show the date